# How can you extract a vector from a bitmap image?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, image-trace, data-extraction

I am not very good at Photoshop; however, my goal is to "extract" black lines from each forest as you can see here.  My supervisor would like me to update them in GIS (Geographic Information System) software.

What are your suggest for me to use them in Photoshop or should I go for Adobe Illustrator ? Those are the two that my agency uses on my computer.

I have a very limited background in Photoshop and not very skilled in Illustrator.  Would anyone help me how to get me there ?

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You can't "extract" vectors from a raster image.  There are no vectors in a raster image file. You can draw them though.  You would use a vector image editor if your intent is to output vectors, not Photoshop. Use the Pen Tool/Bézier tool.  I don't know why you would need to do this however, since most GIS software generally has drawing tools anyway.  Perhaps it would be better to look up a tutorial on how to digitise a map in your preferred GIS software.  There is a GIS Stack Exchange if you have problems. You'll have  problems using that image BTW as it's badly distorted

Comment: Thank you. I am very skilled in GIS using ArcGIS Pro . I want to throw my question and want to see opinions out there . So I thought of another way is to extract it through the image in either Photoshop or Illustrator. Yes I have my profile in GIS Stack Exchange but I didnt think  it was apporiate place to post it there and instead here.

Comment: Photoshop is practically useless for vector output. It's a raster image editor, really the wrong kind of software.  Illustrator has an auto trace function, but it doesn't work well on something as complex as this. The amount of cleaning up you'd have to do would make it more trouble than it's worth. It would be quicker and easier to simply trace over it, to redraw it manually. See an example using [Auto Trace on your map here](https://imgur.com/xrhtfgB).  Since ArcGIS already has drawing tools, I can't honestly see the point in using Illustrator at all.

Comment: @BillyKerr   That screenshot helps !! Yes you are right from what I see it looks a lot of work..

Comment: Did you draw on top of the map? if so you can istead trace with a wacom intuous instead. Also this would be much easier if you could shoot without a glare, with a tele objective and flatten the map

Comment: @joojaa - No.  Do not hae wacom.

Comment: @PROBERT i understand just saying if this is a persostent workflow for you then you might consider getting one.

Comment: @joogaa,  as a GIS Specialist I have heard numerous of issues with the wacom from other users that use it.. But maybe for you or anyone in Graphic Design may be different than ours...  thanks again

Comment: Well i hear people having consistent problems with a lot of things, like with windows, osX, linux, Illustrator, Inkscape, ArcGIS, QGIS etc. Everybody has problems with stuff. Yes the tablet is not a silver bullet, but it does handle this one particular use case perfectly (yes i have traced maps with this in QGIS). As long as you don't move view digitally or physically. Beyond this a tablet is a bit, meh.  Though similarly there's no reason why this couldn't be auto traced you just need a better picture.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**

You should use both Illustrator and Photoshop.

**Intro**

You can do this, reasonably well, with a bit of preparation. Now, not with the image you have though. Having reflective highlights, JPEG compression and a small file size makes the task much harder than it needs to be.

So first try to find a flatbed scanner, failing that put the image on a wall behind a glass, so its flat and photograph from as far away as possible with a tripod with a zoom lens, and some movable light. Make sure you have no reflections of lights.

In ideal conditions, though you would have drawn the map, on a transparent sheet that is on top of your map, this way it would be easier to separate the background form the other parts. Alternatively you would use a pen that has a color that is very high chroma so its easier to separate from background. (Black is not entirely ideal)

**Note**: Not going to deal with the reflection, or straighten image. Its not central to the tracing discussion. It is central to mapping discussion though.

**Cleaning your image (optional)**

Now tracing works best when you have a clean, clear image. The background is going to make the auto tracers job really hard. Ideally you would have just the black color that you want to trace and nothing else. So lets try to clean this in Photoshop.

First you don't really need all color data, so lets open the Channels palette and see what color channel has the least clutter. In the current image to my mind that's the red channel. That is usually enough for further processing. But in this case one can  clean things even more. So do some channel math with **Image → Calculation** for even better results: So multiply the inverse of red, green and result of that with blue you get a pretty decent starting point:

[image]

**Image 1**: Inverse of inverses of channels multiplied together.

The process so far lost some contrast, So lets bring it back and at the same time kill data on the grayer are of the plane. Ideally one would like local contrast, but a global adjustment will suffice as we don't want to use too much time on cleaning up. So a curves adjustment it is:

[image]

**Image 2**: Added contrast and removed clutter with a curves adjustment.

Looking good still some Clutter but much less stuff. So now its time for removing salt and pepper noise with **Filter → Noise → Despecle**.

**Tracing it**

Ideally you would clean the image quickly with a brush at this point. But lets see what the auto tracer in Illustrator thinks on this. Put the method to layered and trace stroke center lines as strokes.

[image]

**Image 3** Final trace.

Then expand and cleanup in illustrator for a minute.

[image]

**Image 4**: End result, in preview and outline mode to show the vectors clearer

Reducing clutter in PS helps with the center line tracing. If you only need outlines feel free to skip playing in Photoshop.

**Note**: This could have gotten much better results if the original image had a higher resolution and no JPEG artifacts. Would also had been better if there was willingness to do a minute or 2 of brush work in photoshop with burn and a white brush.

**Alternative workflows**

Now, the real question is would it have been easier to draw all of this in illustrator or your GIS application to begin with? Or by tracing on top what you have?

Realistically, tracing the image you have by hand takes about 10-20 minutes. Which is less or equal work than redoing the steps here. Obviously worth and effort is up to you. Maybe you need to do thousands of these who knows.

Comment: very interesting !  I will need to request to get an Illustrator  from my agency  so I could use it on my computer . Problem I worked on this image in ArcGIS Pro and using the georeference and if I bring it in either Photoshop or Illustrator and it will lose the georeferenced file or attach to it but I think there is a way around to make it happened.

Comment: @PROBERT you can get the adobe suite on trial for 7 Days. You can also do same with gimp/krita and potrace/inkscape too.

Answer (score 0):

As your object is a vector image, your choice of software should be Illustrator. I don't use that program, rather I use Inkscape which has similar utility.

Within AI, (Adobe Illustrator), you'll find a feature which allows you to import the image which will be a bitmap.

For the minimal outlines you require, it will be easier to manually trace the vectors on a separate image layer. The map is rather cluttered, making the function of tracing the bitmap rather cumbersome.

If you require the text, you'll get more attractive results using the AI text tool, of course.

Once fully traced, you can delete the bitmap layer and export the drawing as a suitable vector file, based on the destination application.

The above is a summary, due to my lack of experience with the specific program, but the searches required to implement the referenced features are also minimal.

- "import bitmap adobe illustrator"
- "create vector layer"
- "delete bitmap layer"
- "export vector file"